# How to rotate string in c?

Tags: c

What I have to do here is I am supposed to read 2 numbers of even and odd rotation i.e. rotation at even and odd indices and rotate them and display resulting string

> ```
> Input: DDU STUDENTS
>         2 3
> Expected Output: EDTNDSUDSUT UT
> My Output:Nothing
> ```

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

void rotatebyone(char str[], int n) 

{

    char x = str[n-1];

    char *ptr=&str[n-2];

    int i;

    for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--)

    {
        str[i] = *ptr;

        ptr--;

    }

    str[0] = x;
}

void rotatearray(char str[], int even_index, int odd_index)

{

    int i,l,j,k;

    int oddstr[10],evenstr[10];

    l=strlen(str);

    for(i=0,j=0,k=0; i<l; i++)

    {
        if(i%2!=0)

        {
            str[i]=oddstr[j];

            j++;

        }

        else

        {
            str[i]=evenstr[k];

            k++;

        }
    }

    oddstr[j]='\0';

    evenstr[k]='\0';

    for(i=0; i<even_index; i++)

        rotatebyone(evenstr,l) ;
    for(i=0; i<odd_index; i++)

        rotatebyone(oddstr,l);

    for(i=0,j=0,k=0; i<l; i++)

    {
        if(i%2!=0)

        {
            str[i]=oddstr[j];

            j++;
        }

        else
        {
            str[i]=evenstr[k];

            k++;

        }
    }

    printf("%s",str);

}


int main()
{

    char str[100];

    int n,m;

    scanf("%[^\n]",str);

    getchar();

    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    rotatearray(str,n,m);

}
```

Comment: In `rotatearray`, you do `str[i]=oddstr[j]`. But, `oddstr` is _uninitialized_. Thus, `str[i]` (which has a valid char) now gets a random/garbage value. I think you want: `oddstr[j]=str[i]`. Likewise for `evenstr`

Comment: Done that now at least I'm getting output but I'm getting input string as output not the required output

Comment: Your `oddstring` and `evenstring` are int arrays; they should be char arrays.

Comment: It is showing some random garbage on doing char arrays oddstr evenstr

Comment: Like UDS UT of the output is coming but before that some garbage is there

Comment: Yes, but that's because your program produces the garbage. Randomly changing the types won't change that. For example, when you try extract `oddstr` and `evenstr`, you do the opposite in fact: You fill `str` with the uninitialized values from these strings. And you pass in the string length to `rotatearray`, but these lengths should be `j` and `k`, not the length of the original string, `l`. You can detect such things by debugging, that is by studying your program and by inspecting its values as it runs.

Comment: Tip: rather than post "DDU STUDENTS" and rotate it, try "0123456789AB".  The uniqueness of each letter will better convey the issues.